# print web page without show the print dialog and this web page

Tags: javascript, spring, web, report

i want to print a document/my report from browser using window.print(). I want browser not to show standart print dialog on current machine and not to show the web page. I have all access to system registry and settings on it. Is there way to tweak the system in this way?

Comment: Very likely not with pure Javascript. Can you use a dedicated program written in another language for the job?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution which was posted on the [codingforums.com - Disabling the print dialog box](http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=224)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Print Test</title>
<script>
      function Print()
         {
          if (document.all) 
             {
               WebBrowser1.ExecWB(6, 6) //use 6, 1 to prompt the print dialog or 6, 6 to omit it; 
                WebBrowser1.outerHTML = "";
             }
         else
            {
             window.print();
             }
         }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <object ID="WebBrowser1" WIDTH="0" HEIGHT="0" 
    CLASSID="CLSID:8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2"> 
    </object>
 <A HREF="#" onClick="Print()">Print this page</a>
</body>
</html>
```

It's noted by the user to only work with IE and fails with all NS browsers but users have validated that it works.